# Swift blocks not working

Tags: swift, block, javascriptcore

I've been trying to figure out how to use JavaScriptCore in swift. I'm running into problems however when I have to deal with blocks as arguments, seems like the block is run immediately and the arguments gets the return value of the block. What am I doing wrong?

Working Objective C code:

```
JSContext* context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init]];
context[@"test"] = ^(NSString *string) {
    //code
};
```

What I've tried:

1:

```
var ctx = JSContext(virtualMachine:JSVirtualMachine())
var ctx["test"] = {(string:NSString)->() in /*code*/ }

//Gives me "'JSContext' does not have a member named 'subscript'"
```

2:

```
var ctx = JSContext(virtualMachine:JSVirtualMachine())
let n: (string: String)->() = {string in /*code*/}

ctx.setObject(n, forKeyedSubscript:"test")

//Gives me "Type '(x: String) -> () does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"
```

3:

```
var ctx = JSContext(virtualMachine:JSVirtualMachine())
let n: (string: String)->() = {string in /*code*/}

ctx.setObject(n as AnyObject, forKeyedSubscript:"test")

//Gives me "Cannot downcast from '(string: String) -> () to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'"
```

Am I missing something here, or is this just a bug in Swift?

Edit:

I've now also tried suggestions from [Cast closures/blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586293/cast-closures-blocks)

```
class Block<T> {
    let f : T
    init (_ f: T) { self.f = f }
}
```

and then

```
ctx.setObject(Block<()->Void> {
        /*code*/
    }, forKeyedSubscript: "test")
```

This solution lets me compile but I get a runtime error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586293/cast-closures-blocks.

Comment: It's similar but different. That question is about dealing with blocks that you receive as return values *from* Objc methods. This one is about passing Swift closures as blocks *to* Objc methods.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It has something to do with how Swift implement closure. You need to use `@convention(block)` to annotate that the closure is ObjC block. Use `unsafeBitCast` to force cast it

```
var block : @convention(block) (NSString!) -> Void = {
   (string : NSString!) -> Void in 
    println("test")
}

ctx.setObject(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "test")
```

from REPL

```
swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> var block : @convention(block)(NSString!) -> Void = {(string : NSString!) -> Void in println("test")}
block: @convention(block)(NSString!) -> Void =
  3> var obj: AnyObject = reinterpretCast(block) as AnyObject
obj: __NSMallocBlock__ = {} // familiar block type
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Only thing, apparently `ctx["test"] =` doesn't work. `ctx.setObject(obj, forKeyedSubscript:"test")` does however. Once again, Thank you, and here is your bounty in 22 hours when I'm able to.

Comment: On Beta6 `reinterpretCast(block) as AnyObject` has been deprecated in favor of `unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject)`

Comment: Actually, that would be `unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self)`

Comment: This line `var ctx["test"] = reinterpretCast(block) as AnyObject` should be `ctx.setObject(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "test")`, tested on Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Comment: With the latest Swift 2 syntax, the block should be defined as `@convention(block) (String) -> Void`

Answer (score 1):

I have a working demo at:

- https://github.com/dankogai/swift-jsdemo

And here is the part that implements block registration:

```
typealias ID = AnyObject!
extension JSContext {
    func fetch(key:NSString)->JSValue {
        return getJSVinJSC(self, key)
    }
    func store(key:NSString, _ val:ID) {
        setJSVinJSC(self, key, val)
    }
    func store(key:NSString, _ blk:()->ID) {
        setB0JSVinJSC(self, key, blk)
    }
    func store(key:NSString, _ blk:(ID)->ID) {
        setB1JSVinJSC(self, key, blk)
    }
    func store(key:NSString, _ blk:(ID,ID)->ID) {
        setB2JSVinJSC(self, key, blk)
    }
}
```

You need a very small objc code and bridging header to make it work.  See the repository for details.