# Error passing Swift array of closures to an Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, swift, block

Define an Objective-C method:

```
@implementation OCObject

+ (void)passArr: (NSArray *)arr {
    void (^aBlock)(NSString *) = arr[0];
    aBlock(@"Crash Here");
}

@end
```

Pass an array contains aBlock in Swift to Objective-C methodA:

```
class SwiftObject {
    class func test() {
        let aBlock: ((String) -> ()) = { str in
            print(str)
        }

        OCObject.passArr([aBlock])
    }
}
```

Then Call `SwiftObject.test()`.

Crash at the line of `aBlock(@"Crash Here")`, and throw `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

However, when I do this all in OC, it's OK.

Why? Is this related to the escaping closure?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46226995/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR That worked. Thanks!