# Convert a swift closure into a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to pass a callback parameter from a swift class to an Objective-C one.
I have searched for the way to do it, but I am struggling, I got this:

```
public typealias RequestCallBackObject = (gbRequest: AnyObject!, status: ServiceStatus, response: AnyObject?) -> ()
```

But how would it be in Objective-C ?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? At a first glance it seems trivial to translate it.

Comment: Have you googled the title of this question?  This looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586293/cast-closures-blocks

Comment: This is what I achieved: I know it's wrong but I'm doing it a close as I think it is. `(void(^)((NSObject *gbRequest) ,(ServiceStatus *status, (NSObject *response))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
-(void) testMethod:(void(^) (id gbRequest, ServiceStatus *serviceStatus, id response) ) blockName {

}
```

Swift's AnyObject equivalent is id in Objective-C.